# React App doesn't make an API call even though they are both running

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

I start the React App.js and it runs on localhost:3000 and then I start the API service that listens on the same port. I send a input file consisted of numbers to the API, and then I expect the API to sort the numbers and give me a result so I can download the new file. But the request never goes through.

This is the app.js for my API:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const app = express();

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/sort', upload.single('inputFile'), (req, res) => {
    const input = req.file.buffer.toString().split('\n').map(Number);
    const result = input.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=result.txt');
    res.send(result.join('\n'));
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('API is listening on port 3000');
});
```

This is the React App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {

  const [inputFile, setInputFile] = useState(null);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null);
  const [processingTime, setProcessingTime] = useState(null);

  const handleFileUpload = (event) => {
    setInputFile(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const startCalculation = async () => {
    const startTime = performance.now();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', inputFile);

    const response = await fetch("https://localhost:3000/sort", {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    setResult(data.body);
    setProcessingTime(performance.now() - startTime);
  };

  const handleDownload = () => {
    const file = new Blob([result], {
      type: 'text/plain'
    });
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = fileURL;
    link.download = 'result.txt';
    link.click();
  };

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <input type="file" onChange={handleFileUpload} />
        <button onClick={startCalculation}>Start Calculation</button>
        <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download Result</button>
        <p>Processing Time: {processingTime}ms</p>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you check the browser developer tools? Specifically the network tab

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch at startCalculation
This error appears, followed by a couple of others.

Comment: Does it say which line? It's usually the number after the filename. So something like `app.js:xx`. xx is your line number. Also, did you look at the network tab? You should get more info there

Comment: Btw, your API doesn't respond with json, so you shouldn't do `response.json()` in the frontend. What you want to do is `response.text()` since the content type is plain text. You also don't need to do `.body` since the text function will return you the body.

Comment: It throws the error on line 21. On this part -> const response = await fetch("https://localhost:3000/sort"

Comment: I changed the response.json() to response.text() and the request went through at least but I don't receive the output file. App.js:21 POST http://localhost:3000/sort 404 (Not Found) -> This is the outcome. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should maybe use http instead of https.

Comment: I changed https to http already. Now I get CANNOT POST /sort error. Do you think I need a app.get method? 
The request url http://localhost:3000/sort is not found.

Comment: No, I think post should be fine. I'm sorry, I'm not going t be able to assist you anymore. You'll have to learn about debugging. Look at the network and console tab, use Google/ChatGPT and try to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out by only changing the https to http, the request goes through. And I changed the port number for the app to 3001, and the API still runs on 3000. Everything worked fine after that.